# ¿Cómo extraer una columna determinada de distintas líneas y guardar los valore en un array?

Tags: bash, awk

Tengo un archivo csv del que necesito extraer la columna 11, y de esta columna quedarme con las líneas de la 3 a la 5, que son valores numéricos. Después, tengo que guardar estos 3 valores en un array. Yo tengo hecho lo siguiente:

```
name=( $(cut -d"," -f11 "/home/compartida/datos.csv" | awk 'NR>=3&&NR<=5')) | echo ${name[@]}
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el anterior comando, me aparece en pantalla la columna 11 entera, no los valores que me interesan. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No le veo mucho problema a tu código, pero podrías intentar con esto para minimizar la cantidad de programas a usar.

```
name=( $(awk -F , 'NR>=3&&NR<=5{print $11}' file.csv ) )
echo "${name[@]}"
```

Donde con `-F ,` podrás intuir que usa como separador las comas y `$11` se refiere al campo 11.

Trata de usar `-v ORS=" "` en `awk` para ver si el problema es con los separadores. Es decir:

```
awk -F , -v ORS=" " 'NR>=3&&NR<=5{print $11}' file.csv
```